# typeorm migrations always creates the migrations

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

Running typeorm migrations always creates the migrations and typeorm_metadata table. These tables keep track of migrations done for the particular schema. But, I'd like to execute some ddl commands with this migration facility. Is there a way to not generate them for a migration ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem to be a logical way to do that, but, the way I got around this is by using the `migrationsTableName`, I changed it dynamically everytime using a word generator, so the net effect would be as if there was no migrations metadata at all. ;-)